# CSS alternating rowbased floating

Tags: css, css-float, css-selectors

Im not sure how exactly to call my problem, hence the cryptic title.

The situation I have is the following:

```
<div class="widget full">foobar</div>
<div class="widget half">left</div>
<div class="widget half">right</div>
<div class="widget half">left</div>
<div class="widget full">foobar</div>
<div class="widget full">foobar</div>
<div class="widget half">left</div>
<div class="widget half">right</div>
```

I let these widgets float left and right, based on the odd or even css:

```
#main > div.widget.full { display: block; width: 100%; }
#main > div.widget.half { display: block; width: 49%; }
#main > div.widget.half:nth-child(2n+1) { float: right; }
```

Works like a charm on the first 2 'half' ones, but the 2 after that get screwed over by the 3rd 'half'. The last 2 are in 'reversed order'. What I need is some sort of reset or other solution that will put the divs in the right place, regardless of what is between them.

If there is no CSS answer for this I can fix it generating them in PHP, but CSS has my preference since its a style-issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: jsfiddle would really help in getting people to understand what you mean since each whole has only *2 halves*

Comment: It looks like you're trying to build a grid layout. CSS cannot reliably do that *yet*. On another note, for clarity use `nth-child(odd)` and `nth-child(even)` notation if that's what you're going for - `n`-notation isn't half as clear to most casual observers.

Comment: If you're outputting the code through PHP, can you not specify the classes through this to give you greater granularity on your divs? or is it just that every other 'half' div floats on the right?

Comment: @AndrewMorris If I can solve things with CSS I'd rather do that, but Im going to solve this with PHP, resetting the counter after every full widget. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you will not able to achieve this via css only.

This selector:

```
#main > div.widget.half:nth-child(2n+1)
```

Will not look for `2n+1` occurrences of `.widget.half` children, but instead will target only `.widget.half` elements that are children number 1, 3, 5, etc.

Comment: I like the fact that this question has been asked and answered by hamsters :)

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, unless there is any reason to say that your `.half` divs need to either stick to the left or right, can't you just apply a `float:left` to each `.half` div, and a `clear:both` to your full ones?

In this example it seems to work fine

CSS

```
#main > div.widget.full {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    outline: solid 1px blue;
    clear:both;
}
#main > div.widget.half {
    display: block;
    width: 49%;
    outline: solid 1px red;
    float:left;
}
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BEbrn/) - I added some colour so it would be more obvious to see.